# Is it possible to connect iPad to xampp server over adhoc WITHOUT internet connection?

Tags: apache, ipad, windows-7, xampp, adhoc

I can connect my iPad directly to my Windows 7 laptop using a Win7 adhoc connection and the laptop's internal wifi.  That much works.  (I tried the alternative of connecting via a wireless router, unsuccessfully.)

Now that the connection is made, I need the iPad to access the XAMPP Apache server that's running on the Win 7 laptop.

I run 'ipconfig' on Windows to find the IP address assigned to the laptop, type this into the iPad's Safari browser address bar, and get "Unable to connect to http://www.192.168.2.5 because you are not connected to the internet."

The 'http://www' is inserted by Safari, I did not type that in.

I also tried including the port that Apache is listening on:  192.168.2.5:80 , with the same result.

I do NOT want to connect to the internet at large (I don't have the two wifi cards necessary to do that), but only to the local Apache server on the Win 7 laptop.

Another answer describes doing this with Bluetooth.  I do not have Bluetooth available on the laptop.

The iPad is running iOS 7.1.2.

I've tried the usual tricks on the iPad, resetting Network Settings, turning on/off Airport, etc.  Still, Safari insists on inserting 'www' in the address and denying the connection.

How do you connect an Ipad2 to a localhost server running on Windows 7 without having a simultaneous internet connection?

Comment: I found a workaround, doing the usual of connecting through a wifi router rather than with a Windows adhoc peer-to-peer connection.  The reason that didn't work before is that the Windows Firewall was blocking I/O for Apache and httpd.  Allow that and it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried entering `http://192.168.2.5:80`

You want the http, just not the www.